# Compile error with inet_addr and sendto

Tags: c, windows

I tried compiling this open source program found in http://www.abc.se/~m6695/udp.html but it's giving an error message. The server program will be running on Ubuntu.

Here is the modified code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
//#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "winsock2.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#define BUFLEN 512
#define NPACK 10
#define PORT 9980

#define SRV_IP "999.999.999.999"

 void diep(char *s)
  {
    perror(s);
    exit(1);
  }

int main(void) {
struct sockaddr_in si_other;
int s, i, slen = sizeof(si_other);
char buf[BUFLEN];

if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1)
    diep("socket");

memset((char *) &si_other, 0, sizeof(si_other));
si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
si_other.sin_port = htons(PORT);
//inet_addr (const) char *SRV_IP);
if (inet_addr(SRV_IP, &si_other.sin_addr) == 0) {
//if (inet_aton(SRV_IP, &si_other.sin_addr) == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "inet_aton() failed\n");
    exit(1);
}

for (i = 0; i < NPACK; i++) {
    printf("Sending packet %d\n", i);
    sprintf(buf, "This is packet %d\n", i);
    if (sendto(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, &si_other, slen) == -1)
        diep("sendto()");
}

closesocket(s);
return 0;
}
```

It gives the following errors:

```
Error   1 error C2660: 'inet_addr' : function does not take 2 arguments [filepath]
Error   2   error C2664: 'sendto' : cannot convert parameter 5 from 'sockaddr_in *' to 'const sockaddr *' [filepath]
```

Comment: Are you trying to use windows headers on a linux box, or am I mistaken there?

Comment: You say that this program will be running on Ubuntu, but from the errors (`C2660`, `C2664`) it appears that you are compiling on windows. You will have more luck if you start with code that is known to work on your target platform, and develop it _on that platform_. If you don't have a ubuntu box handy, grab `VirtualBox` and an Ubuntu livecd image. It's quite easy to set up a virtual machine that you can use to test your code.

Answer (score 0):

inet_addr takes just one argument, I guess the example code you got was from a different sort of system.  See here: http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_addr and change the call to something like:

```
if ((si_other.sin_addr = inet_addr(SRV_IP) != INADDR_NONE) {
```

As for the sendto call, you probably just need to cast the argument to the required type as given in the compiler error.